# Is there a word for 'something someone wants most to change about their appearance'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm a person who helps people create characters for books, and I've been looking and looking, but I could never find a word that had the meaning of '*something someone wants to change most about their appearance*'. It is an odd request, but I have the distinct feeling that something should exist out there. For example:

- They would be willing to do almost anything to anything to change their height.
- Personally, they thought their brown hair was just so dull- to bad they couldn't afford to get actual hair dye.
- Blue eyes were plain- why not get coloured contacts instead?

Comment: I think we need a sentence with a blank in it. Your examples are confusing, and it's not clear to me if you want a noun, a verb, or an adjective; though your stated request appears to be a noun.

Comment: I don't know why, but the most common term for this is the person's *least favorite* feature or body part. That sounds like it should mean something you like about yourself, just not as much as you like other parts, but it can (and often does) mean something you absolutely hate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a one-word answer, as most people have many things about themselves they'd like to change, but how about *flaw* or *defect* or *imperfection*?

M-W:

> [*flaw*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flaw): a
>   defect in physical structure or form; an imperfection or weakness and
>   especially one that detracts from the whole or hinders effectiveness
>
> [*defect*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/defect):
>   something that spoils the appearance or completeness of a thing
>
> [*imperfection*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/imperfection):
>   something that spoils the appearance or completeness of a thing

One's personal pet *flaw*, *defect*, or *imperfection* might be that one's nose is too long, teeth are too crooked, butt is too large, breasts are too small (or large), hands are too small (you know who I'm talking about here), voice is too high pitched, etc. All are one word.

Comment: +1, but I think *fatal flaw* is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with "fatal flaw."  A "fatal flaw" is the flaw that brings about disaster or downfall, such as a fatal flaw in a mechanism that causes it to fail under specific circumstances and cause an accident or the fatal flaw in a man's character that caused his downfall.

I might go with "figure flaw" or "worst feature."